# MDX Help SSRS Query Designer MDX Calculated Member & MDX Operator Filter Expression

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssas, mdx

I have 2 questions in the SSRS Query Designer for my SSAS tabular model.  I create a calculated Member column that basically says, IF this other column = "Last Invoice Date", put "Last Invoice Date" as the value, otherwise, put a different column's value in, "FiscalMonthLastDay":

`IIF([Invoice Date].[Relative Date].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION ="Last Invoice Date",
"Last Invoice Date",
[Invoice Date].[FiscalMonthLastDay].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION)`

When i drag that new field in, it works but its creating extra rows in my results. I added before & after screen shot (erased some sensitive data). I can't figure out how to get it to not show the extra rows?

Before: 
[image]

After:

[image]

My 2nd question is, i would then like to filter my data set to only where this new calculated member matches another column. So I am doing the MDX operator in the filters section and thought something like this would work, but i can't get it to (its the same formula as above):

[image]

If anyone knows where to get some good examples of how this MDX operator is used, that would be great !

Thanks !

Comment: I've realized I can probably skip creating a column, then trying to filter by that column if it's possible to do an OR statement. Something like:            

[Invoice Date].[Relative Date].&[Last Invoice Date]
OR
[Invoice Date].[FiscalMonthLastDay].[FiscalMonthLastDay].currentmember.MEMBER_CAPTION = [Invoice Date].[Date].[Date].currentmember.MEMBER_CAPTION

I am getting the following error though: 
The Axis0 function expects a tuple set expression for the  argument. A string or numeric expression was used.

The filter works if i just do 1st part of the expression.Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand this:

```
[Invoice Date].[Relative Date].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION ="Last Invoice Date"
```

Looking at your screenprints `[Relative Date]` is a date - so how can `MEMBER_CAPTION` be equal to "Last Invoice Date" ?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand it myself ! The field is dynamic field where the SSAS tabular model logic replaces the last available invoice date (new invoices get loaded every day), with the phrase "Last Invoice Date". We then filter a report to  = "Last Invoice Date" and the report will always give you the latest invoice's data. I pieced the logic together with very little MDX expierence. It almost works but not quite because of the issue i'm having. I am open to any alternatives though.

Comment: this "Last Invoice Date" is not in the screenprints - so in those sscreenprints CurrentMember is never "Last Invoice Date". The definition of the function currentmember is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144948.aspx

Comment: Yes sorry i should have explained in more detail- further down in the result set screen shot, there are values of "Last Invoice Date". My IIF statement works for those values, I was just trying to get rid of the rows with NULLs in the measures. Then filter result set somehow by only including rows where the new calculated member equals the Relative Date field.